# How to Handle Bulk Updates of Work Items in a TFS 2010 Server Plugin?

Tags: plugins, tfs

I wrote a TFS 2010 server plugin that updates a field in a work item, when ever the same work item makes some specified state transition (e.g. from Resolved to Active). 
The plug in works great when I only update a single work item (with Team Explorer or Visual Studio).

However, when I try to make a bulk update, editing 50 work items at once, using Excel 2010, the plugin crashes, and both excel and TFS hang for roughly 5 minutes. The exception I get (I logged it in the event handler) is:
**Exception Message: TF26174: Team Foundation timed out trying to connect to the server. Check that you have a network connection and that the Team Foundation Server is available. If the problem persists, contact your Team Foundation Server administrator. (type ConnectionException)**

I checked and other, better known and refined plugins such as [TFS Aggregator](http://tfsaggregator.codeplex.com) has the same problem.

Does anybody know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I came up with a way to write a robust and durable server plugin. I blogged about it [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/assafstone/archive/2011/07/29/how-to-write-a-robust-tfs-server-plugin-with-job-extensions.aspx).

Assaf.